# Callback was already called in async module

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have the following array:

```
var files = [
 {
  name: 'myfile.txt'
 },
 {
  name: 'myfile2.txt'
 }
];
```

I'm using async for access this objects and send them to extraction, like this:

extraction function:

```
var extraction = function(file, callback) {
  // extract

  // return text
  callback(text);
};
```

Using async

```
var fn = function(files, callback) {
  Async.mapLimit(files, 3000, function(file, done) {
   extraction(file, function(texts) {
     done(texts);
   });
  }
}, function(texts) {
  callback(texts);
}
```

How i need call:

```
fn(files, function(texts) {
 console.log(texts); // new objects, now with text's
});
```

Like this, i'm receiving the following error:

```
Done was already called.
```

This happens because i can't call the done inside the async two ways, and i'm doing that.

To around this problem, i'm doing this inside the Async:

```
if (files.length === texts.length) {
  done(texts);
}
```

So will compare. Files size is the same as texts size? Yes? So you can call the done.

This will work perfectly. The problem with this is that i can't pass a error argument inside a else statement, like this:

```
if (files.length === texts.length) {
  done(null, texts);
} else {
  done('ERROR'!);
}
```

First because would be call in every loop, so will cause the same error:

```
Done was already called.
```

And even if i could, would break the loop because will be called in the first looping.

How can i fix this? I need a light here :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is not braced correctly and the callback arguments were not in the proper position in a couple of places:

```
var fn = function(files, callback) {
  Async.mapLimit(files, 3000, function(file, done) {
   extraction(file, function(texts) {
     done(texts);
   });
  }
}, function(texts) {
  callback(texts);
}
```

It should be:

```
var fn = function (files, callback) {
    Async.mapLimit(files, 3000, function (file, done) {
        extraction(file, function (texts) {
            done(null, texts);
        });
    }, function (err, texts) {
        callback(texts);
    });
}
```

`Async.mapLimit()` takes four arguments.  You were not passing the fourth argument correctly.  In fact, if you paste your code into http://jshint.com/, it will show you where the errors are (frankly I'm surprised that the code even ran).

Here's an article that shows you some `Async.mapLimit()` coding examples that work just like you are trying to do: [Concurrency level (async.mapLimit)](http://promise-nuggets.github.io/articles/16-map-limit.html)

Comment: @JoãoCalvin - I made some more corrections.  The done callback has to pass an error value as the first argument (`null` if no error).  And, the final callback is called with the data as the 2nd argument, an error code is the first argument.  Also, is `extraction()` asynchronous?

Comment: Yes, extraction is asynchronous.. i'm going to try your code.